# Signal Fluctuation WiMax at Night (Remote Wells Comms)

Tags: wireless

We have a heap of newly installed WiMax devices that we use to communicate with remote wells. During the day, they operate fine. But as night time approaches and all through the night, the signal is hugely disrupted and we have large error rates.

Our main tower has 4 WiMax devices to cover the 360 degrees, and the wells are between 5 and 15kms away. Our telecomms guys aren't much help at the moment.

This is in the desert, in Egypt.

Thoughts?

[image: WiMax Comms]

Comment: What's the air humidity at day and night in the desert? Can you use a spectrum analyzer or simply some SDR to check for nighttime interferers (military comms, radar)?

Comment: Tower height above sand level? Does polarization help? Does smooth sand become a perfect phase-shifter and thus inserts multi-pathing?

Comment: Does a daytime breeze halt at sunset, and the sand settles down slowly, even the finest particles. to form a perfect reflecting glass? Which of the 6 paths have dunes? Which of the 6 paths include wet oases? What is that perfectly repeating peak/null in the lower right strength plot?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf ah, good thought! Maybe Thaw makes the desert soil conduct better, and if design was bad/tower not high enough / antennas not directive enough, that'd be within the first or second Fresnel zone

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Telecoms seems to agree. He called it 'ducting', and says it can happen close to sea level over flat surfaces (desert). He is going to install a reflector dish and a new module that has vertical and horizontal polarisation. If that means anything. I'll update after the tests are done.

Comment: Yes, using horizontal and vertical polarization should help, as well as increasing the transmitter power and the receiver "band pass Q" so that "noise" around the selected frequency is rejected.  You might be able to operate at a different frequency, one that is not susceptible to the "noise" you are encountering.